# Simple client/server looses lines in transmission (boost/Windows)

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, boost, visual-studio-express

First environment data: Windows 7, c:\boost (1.55.0), Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express (SP1)

Here is the simplest functional version of a client/server you can think of, using new line ended lines as ways of transportation (disregard lack of limits, and time outs, please!)

The server waits until the client sends `"f\n"`, and then sends back trimmed lines from an local text file back to the client. The very last line holds a dot (.) only which indicates end of transmission (disregard fact that there can be a dot in the file.)

## What is the problem?

Output on the server shows that all lines are sent away back to the client. Client, however, shows that there are some lines missing.

I do not see where is there possibility for the transmission to miss data.

Here is the fully functional server code. Build it, and run on the server without arguments.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

void writeln( boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& socket, const std::string& text )
{
    std::cout << "writeln " << text << "\n" ;
    boost::system::error_code error ;
    boost::asio::write( socket, boost::asio::buffer( text + "\n", text.length() + 1 ), boost::asio::transfer_all(), error );
}

bool readln( boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& socket, std::string& text )
{
    try
    {
        boost::asio::streambuf response ;
        boost::asio::read_until( socket, response, "\n" ) ;

        std::istream response_stream( &response ) ;
        std::getline( response_stream, text ) ;

        if ( text != "." )
            return true ;
    }
    catch( const std::exception& e )
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << "\n" ;
    }

    return false ;
}

static char* trim( char* line )
{
    size_t len = strlen( line ) ;

    while ( len > 0 && ( line[ len - 1 ] == ' ' || line[ len - 1 ] == '\t' || line[ len - 1 ] == '\n' || line[ len - 1 ] == '\r' ))
        len-- ;

    line[ len ] = 0 ;

    return line ;
}

static void f( boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& socket )
{
    std::string fname = "c:\\f.txt" ;
    FILE* f = fopen( fname.c_str(), "r" ) ;
    if ( f != NULL )
    {
        char line[ 1024 ] ;

        while ( fgets( line, sizeof( line ), f ) != NULL )
            writeln( socket, trim( line )) ;

        fclose( f ) ;
    }
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[])
{
    try
    {
        boost::asio::io_service        io_service ;
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor( io_service, boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), 8080 )) ;

        for (;;)
        {
            boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket( io_service ) ;
            std::string                  cmd ;

            acceptor.accept( socket ) ;
            while ( readln( socket, cmd ))
            {
                std::cout << cmd << "\n" ;
                if ( cmd == "f" )
                    f( socket ) ;

                writeln( socket, "." ) ;
            }
        }
    }
    catch( const std::exception& e )
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << "\n" ;
    }

    return 0 ;
}
```

And here comes the client's code. Call `prog 127.0.0.1 f` to see result.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>

void writeln( boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& socket, const std::string& text )
{
    boost::system::error_code error ;
    boost::asio::write( socket, boost::asio::buffer( text + "\n", text.length() + 1 ), boost::asio::transfer_all(), error );
}

bool readln( boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& socket, std::string& text )
{
    try
    {
        boost::asio::streambuf response ;
        boost::asio::read_until( socket, response, "\n" ) ;
        std::istream response_stream( &response ) ;
        std::getline( response_stream, text ) ;
        std::cout << "readln " << text << "\n" ;
        if ( text != "." )
            return true ;
    }
    catch( const std::exception& e )
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << "\n" ;
    }

    return false ;
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if ( argc > 2 )
        try
        {
            boost::asio::io_service      io_service ;
            boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket( io_service ) ;
            std::string                  text ;

            socket.connect( boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint( boost::asio::ip::address::from_string( argv[ 1 ]), 8080 )) ;

            writeln( socket, argv[ 2 ]) ;

            while ( readln( socket, text ))
                std::cout << text << "\n" ;

            return 0 ;
        }
        catch( const std::exception& e )
        {
            std::cerr << e.what() << "\n" ;
            return 1 ;
        }
}
```

Comment: KK. I know the answer. In `readln()` I am using buffered  class (istream) which 'eats' more than a line, but then, I am not consuming all the data.

Comment: You are consuming all the data received, it gets "consumed" by the `streambuf` that you dispose of. If you keep the `streambuf` alive, then you can still read the unused buffer contents next time around, yes.

Answer (score 1):

The `bool readln( boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& socket, std::string& text )` function in the client version is incorrect. Uses buffered io which eats more than should.

It's not the best version, but instead of client's current code:

```
    while ( readln( socket, text ))
        std::cout << text << "\n" ;
```

It could do:

```
    boost::asio::streambuf response ;

    for(;;)
    {
        boost::asio::read_until( socket, response, "\n" ) ;
        std::istream response_stream( &response ) ;
        std::getline( response_stream, text ) ;
        if ( text == "." )
            break ;
        std::cout << text << "\n" ;
    }
```